# asp.net grid view and dataList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sqldatareader

I need help with a part of my website I'm coding. I have a listBox_Products which is populated with sqlServerDataSource. When I click on a product, it will display a corresponding picture along a gridview with productPrice and productName. The gridview is databound programmatically in the codebehind, on the indexChange event. I have a button, addToShoppingCart. On the button_Click event, I want to add the item the user chose to the shopping cart (it's on the same page), I have a second gridView, which received the item the user chose and displays it. This is where I'm stuck. I know I can't append to gridview, and I know it has to be databound. My logic is this: get the first item user chooses, add it to a datatable, insert into second gridview. Now if the user chooses another product, same logic, except this time, I would add a new row, and add the new data to the new row, keeping old row as well. Problem is I can't figure out how to do this. I'm not very experienced in datatable.

This is my code behind.

This is my code to get the product from sql server:

```
Private Sub GetProducts()

    Dim TechShopConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Zapata_IT_DataBaseConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim TechCon As New SqlConnection(TechShopConnectionString)
    Dim TechCmd As New SqlCommand()

    Dim index As Integer = ListBox_Products.SelectedIndex()

    TechCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    TechCmd.CommandText = "GetAllProductInformationByID"
    TechCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = index
    TechCmd.Connection = TechCon

    Try
        TechCon.Open()
        GridView2.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found"
        GridView2.DataSource = TechCmd.ExecuteReader()
        GridView2.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        TechCon.Close()
        TechCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is my code to add item to the second gridview:

```
Protected Sub Button_AddToCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_AddToCart.Click
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim index As Integer = ListBox_Products.SelectedIndex()

    Try
        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Zapata_IT_DataBaseConnectionString").ConnectionString
        conn = New SqlConnection(connString)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "GetAllProductInformationByID"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = index
        cmd.Connection = conn

        conn.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        Dim dr2 As DataRow

        dataTableCheckOut.NewRow()
        dataTableCheckOut.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)

        GridView_CheckOut.DataSource = dataTableCheckOut
        GridView_CheckOut.DataBind()

    Catch ex As SqlException

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

    ' Enter code here
```

As you can see I'm pretty lost. I know the logic is fine, but I cant figure out the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the information about what is in the users cart from page to page (which you should want to), you should be saving the items in the users cart to the database. If you go to Amazon.Com, add something to your cart, then come back later, even on another compter, you can see the items in your cart, based on your login.

Since you know how to read data from the database, this should be easy for you. Just add the info to this new *cart* table and read it when you need it. Maybe every page shows the number of items and you just need the count but when viewing the cart of checking out, you need to show all the info.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Im going to give it a shot. either way, do you know any way to do what i initially though about??? Thanks.

Comment: yes, if your grid is tied to a datatable, you can add new rows using `datatable.NewRow`, but then, after filling in your default data on the new record, you have to call `datatable.Rows.Add({Your new row})`. One issue is that the grid will not know there is a new record because your datasource (DataTable) does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged. So, you have to set the datasource = nothing and then change it back to the datatable. I would suggest using a ObservableCollection or BindingSource to avoid having to reset your DataSource.  Or wait, your doing ASP.

Comment: ... Your next question is going to be how to keep the data from page to page, refer to the above answer.